# Google Analytics Plugin and one author name not appearing

Tags: wordpress, plugins, google-analytics

I have 30 authors and all is right except one author which is not appearing on Google Custom Variables. 
What to do in this case? 
Is there any syntax errors related to the name maybe? There's a little apostrophe in the author last name. Maybe this is the reason? How to verify? I have removed the apostrophe and it still not appearing!

I really need your help!
Many thanks

PS/ I'm using the Google Analytics Plugin for WordPress http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/google-analytics-for-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fgoogle-analytics-debugger%2Fjnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna%3Fhl%3Den&ei=h0KBUp_LEIrOhAf0mIH4BA&usg=AFQjCNGTv_4m9B4Xa50M46BAYT_NlAlK8w&bvm=bv.56146854,d.ZG4) for Google Chrome. This will allow you to easily debug what's being sent to Google Analytics.

In Google Chrome browse to your WordPress installation, then:

- Find a blogpost written by the 'problem' author and see what custom variables are being sent.
- Check your [Chrome Developer Tools Console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) for JavaScript errors with the author's name

  - Perhaps the name has single or double quotes that can break the Google Analytics JavaScript
- Check that the author metadata (or user data) is correctly specified within WordPress.

  - Perhaps the author data is not set correctly - display name is blank perhaps

Comment: Hi, It's related to the apostrophe in the name. It affects the JavaScript code, check out here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/author-name-omara-breaks-ga-tags. Now my concern is how to fix the error? I have removed the apostrophe from wordpress author name, disabled, deleted and reactivated the plugin but still haven't solved the issue..